# Performing subtract operation between square hatches

Tags: python, dxf, ezdxf

I am able to write dxf file using Python ezdxf function which can generate a square.
But I want to draw another smaller square and want to to subtract it from bigger square to get an annular ring.
How can I do that using ezdxf  function?

Here is my code which can generate square hatch using ezdxf and write it into a DXF file.

```py
import ezdxf

doc = ezdxf.new("R2010")  # create a new DXF drawing (AutoCAD 2010)
msp = doc.modelspace()  # we are working in model space

msp.add_line((10, 10), (0, 10))
msp.add_line((0, 10), (0, 0))
msp.add_line((0, 0), (10, 0))
msp.add_line((10, 0), (10, 10))

doc.saveas("hatch_with_spline_edge.dxf")  # save DXF drawing
```

Comment: What is `i`? `10`?

Comment: yes, sorry, i = 10, First I defined the vertices in terms of variable i but then replaced it with 10 while pasting the code here.